# how to use mysql resultset as iterator

Tags: ruby

I am using `mysql2/em` types to query my database from an EventMachine code:

```
database.query("select * from `mytable`").callback {|rows|
    ...
}
```

Usually I would iterate over the resulting rows using `rows.foreach` method. But now I need to iterate over the rows "on demand", when a certain event occurs. Something like:

```
row = rows.get_next
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what I came up with:

```
EM.run {
  database.query('select * from mytable').callback {|rows|
    e = rows.to_enum

    loop {
      p e.next
    }
    EM.stop
  }.errback {|e|
    p e
    EM.stop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my event machine projects when I need to have a DB connection I use ActiveRecord, so the abstraction layer works same as Rails

This is a simple example using bundler

#### Gemfile

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'activerecord'
gem 'mysql2'
```

#### config/database.yml

```
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: bd_coop
pool: 5
username: sps_admin
password: sps_admin_db
host: localhost
```

#### config/database.rb

```
database = YAML.load_file(File.expand_path('../database.yml', __FILE__))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => database["adapter"],
  :database => database["database"],
  :password => database["password"],
  :host => database["host"],
  :username => database["username"]
)
```

#### lib/model.rb

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = "model"

end
```

#### lib/server.rb

```
require "active_record"
require File.expand_path('../../config/db_connection', __FILE__)

module EchoServer
  def receive_data data
     Model.create(:data => data)
     send_data Model.all
  end

end


EventMachine.run {
    puts "Server started"
    EventMachine.start_server "0.0.0.0", 8082, EchoServer
}
```